# fulltext search in elasticsearch and laravel scout is not working

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, full-text-search, kibana, laravel-scout

i implemented `elasticsearch` and `laravel scout` in laravel 9.x application

and i also installed `matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch` repository as driver for scout

**but the problem is: When the searched word is not written completely, no result will be found!**

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Laravel\Scout\Attributes\SearchUsingFullText;
use Laravel\Scout\Attributes\SearchUsingPrefix;


class Post extends Model
{
    use searchable;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];


    #[SearchUsingPrefix(['title'])]
    #[SearchUsingFullText(['title'])]
    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'body' => $this->body
        ];
    }
}
```

insert in db and index in elasticsearch:

```
\App\Models\Link::create([
   'title' => 'elasticsearch tutorial',
   'body'  => 'body...'
]);
```

trying to search:

```
$post = \App\Models\Post::search('elasticsear')->get();
dd($post);
```

the `elasticsear` word in incomplete and no result will be found

Comment: I'm stuck with a similar issue, but I'm using the database driver instead.
For some reason, it just returns and empty array/collection.

Comment: btw you have `'title' => $this->body` as well.
Change it to `'body' => $this->body`.
Please change and check once again.

Comment: hi. that 'title' => $this->body was a typo. i think I solved the problem using the " * " sign, but I don't know if this is the right way or not. $post = \App\Models\Post::search('*elasticsear*')->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one https://sigmie.com/docs/v0/laravel-scout

It supports the newest Laravel Scout